# arrow-symbols won't rotate

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, symbology

I created my own marker symbols (arrows) for point features. Now I want to rotate them with the Rotation-Tool from the Editor-Toolbar, but the Arrows always snap back to their original horizontal position.

What am I missing?

To rotate the arrow i proceeded as follows:

- start editing session and select the feature layer containing the arrow symbols
- select the arrow-symbol i want to rotate
- select the rotation-tool
- select the arrow and drag it in the wanted position

--> and then it just snaps back to its original position...

News: When I select rotation for onw of the attribute table columns in the layer properties, rotating seems to work but nuw the symbol just *disappears*!

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps you in this situation, but pressing `Space` temporarily disables snapping.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are trying to rotate symbols for point features. Rotating the point features themselves won't work. A point is a point, and has no direction. You should be able to perform symbol rotation through the layer's symbology tab, choose advanced and then rotation. You will need a field with rotation values for this in geographic or arithmetic degrees. I don't know exactly what you're doing when the symbol disappears, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: This seems to have been the problem - when I create a new field in the attribute table and then select that field in the symbology tap (as you described) I can rotate the symbols (which are arrows) and they neither snap back nor disappear :) Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand it correctly, you are trying to rotate symbols for point features. Rotating the point features themselves won't work. A point is a point, and has no direction. You should be able to perform symbol rotation through the layer's symbology tab, choose advanced and then rotation. You will need a field with rotation values for this in geographic or arithmetic degrees.